# Application shows session_start(): Failed to read session data: on browser

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, session, apache, linux

I have hosted a website using a backup and when I access it through a web browser, it shows me **error** and I have changed configuration.php file from:

```
public $error_reporting = 'none';
```

To:

```
public $error_reporting = 'development';
```

then the browser shows me:

> Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: user (path: /var/lib/php/sessions) in /var/www/html/web/libraries/joomla/session/handler/native.php on line 260
> Error: Failed to start application: Failed to start the session

Comment: Can you confirm what you have Session Handler set to in the Global Configuration? Does it work if you change it from filesystem to Database or back the other way? Have there been any other changes to the environment recently on your hosting account like a change in PHP software levels? The message indicates that sessions can't be retrieved so it could be data base corruption, directory can't be found or is not accessible due to permissions or other security features of your hosting account.

Answer (score 1):

This error usually means that Joomla has failed to connect to the database.

Check that the database credentials are correct.

Also check that the relevant options e.g. `mysqli` are enabled in PHP. If you are using cPanel, PHP options are found under "Select PHP Version".